# Struggling to install QGIS from source in RHEL 6.4

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, linux, red-hat

I have installed QGIS from source in Ubuntu using the [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) link. In ubuntu I compiled qgis from source without any problem.

but now I moved to RHEL 6.4, not able to run QGIS from source. The steps I have followed to install QGIS from source are described below.

First, I have added all repository which required by QGIS. They are as follows:

```
devtools-1.1.repo
elgis-testing.repo
elgis.repo
epel-testing.repo
epel.repo
remi-php70.repo
remi-safe.repo
remi.repo
rhel-source.repo
rpmforge.repo
slc6-extras.repo
slc6-os.repo
slc6-updates.repo
```

and I also installed Python 2.7, QScintilla2, GLIBC 2.14 from source because of version mismatching.

Then,I followed [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) link to build the QGIS, till this stage everything is fine. Build completed without any error.

After launching the QGIS application, It is showing an error saying that 
"Import Error:cannot import name Qgsfeature". this error is related to python versions, As I have two python versions installed my machine(Python 2.66 and Python 2.7). then I set the PYTHONPATH, But it is not affecting to the Application, So still displaying the same error.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Unfortunately, questions about compiling software, even GIS software, are general software development  problems, more suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will post it in StackOverflow

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/33123770/820534